# How to avoid Flickering in my SDI application?

Tags: mfc

I created an SDI application in vc++ having multiple views in it. When i re-size the SDI application it is getting flickered. I tried returning "TRUE" in "oneraseBackGround" function.
But that is causing my application refresh issue.

Please guide me on the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **double-buffering**. Let me share with you an interesting link where a class which solves your problem is implemented:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/flickerfree.aspx

I hope it can solve your problem.